# Angular CLI webpack does not show warning for unused variables

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

If I can customize the CLI to show the unused variables, as is shown by create-react-app CLI it will be really helpful.

Comment: You should request this feature on the project's [GitHub via an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues). This is not a place to request features for an open source project. Also arguably this is a linter's job not that of a MV* framework's CLI.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app does it with eslint [[ref]](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/package.json#L22). I agree with @Joshua Barnett on submitting an issue to Github, but you could also integrate it yourself. See [Getting started with ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started).